# Hot swap Video files during development on Node js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file, server

I am currently working on a video streaming website with React and Nodejs. The problem I am having is that I often switch out the videofiles on the backend server, but I noticed that when I swap files and refresh my Browser, the files can't be loaded from the server and I get an error on both frontend and backend that the file I want to load is not found. I then have to manually clear the (chrome) browser cache to get it to work again.

I tried avoiding the problem by turning off the backend server and changing the page to another page without video before swapping files, but that doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to swap out files without having to clear my browser cache all the time?